# Relativelayout and View Gone

Tags: android

**I have a layout like this:**

[image]

You can see the little play icon there. What i want is if i give visibility gone to this little play icon, my view should look like this:

[image]

But my current status of if i give to visibility gone to little play icon:

[image]

**My xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/conversation_list_border">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_color_1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="Tolgay Toklar"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/unreadMessageBg"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/konusmalar_chat_count_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unreadMessageCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bioText"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView22"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/send_voice_record" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can i resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `imageView22` and `bioText` into another layout. The key point is to set `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` for `bioText`.
Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/conversation_list_border">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_color_1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="Tolgay Toklar"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/unreadMessageBg"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/konusmalar_chat_count_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unreadMessageCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nameText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bioText"
            android:layout_width="199dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView22"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView22"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:text="Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?"
            android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/send_voice_record" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put imageView22 (I guess this is the play imageview) and bioText inside a relative layout, like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameText">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/send_voice_record" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bioText"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView22"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?Selam Nasılsın?"
        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When you make the imageview invisible, then the TextView will take the space that the imagview was previously.  Of course you must fix other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. ConstraintLayout is basically a newer, better version of RelativeLayout, so the conversion shouldn't be too bad. Fortunately for you, when a view is `GONE` in ConstraintLayout, any view that was constrained to it behaves as though the target view is still there, just 0 size.

Here's your layout using `ConstraintLayout`. I've deleted all attributes other than ids and constraints, to make it more obvious what constraints you need to use.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/unreadMessageBg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bioText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView22"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameText"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that if you aren't using `androidx`, and are still using the old support libraries, the tag is this instead:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```